# Inequality of polynomial on neighbour quadrilaterals

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, numerical-methods, lp-spaces

Let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) denotes the vector space of polynomials of degree $\le p$ in each variable $x_1,x_2$. Let $v_h\in \mathbb{Q}_p(K\cup K')$, where $K,K'\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ are two quadrilateral of $diam\sim h$, $h>0$ fixed, both affine to the square $(0,1)^2$, which either share a vertex either a side (note that we are in the finite element context).

It holds
$$
\|v_h\|_{L^\infty(K)}\le C \|v_h\|_{L^\infty(K')}.
$$

What does $C>0$ depend upon? What happens if $\operatorname{dist}(K,K')\sim C_1 h$?

Comment: As an engineer I have done pretty much on finite elements, but I have no idea what you are saying.

Comment: What does appear mysterious to you? @HandeBruijn

Comment: Can you formulate in layman (I.e. engineering) terms what the symbols mean?

Comment: Sorry, now it's me who doesn't know what you are talking about. Just tell me what you don't understand. Anyway, finite element is just the background here. Probably the tile is misleading

Comment: $v_h=$ ? , $\mathbb{P}_k=$ ? OK: $K,K'$ are two triangles in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ . How is the $diam\sim h$ of a triangle defined? What is $\|v_h\|_{L^\infty(K)}$ ? I suppose the latter is some norm in some space; what norm in what space? The key problem is that I am an elder physicist by education and I am not (at all) familiar with set theoretic notation.

Comment: What does $\Bbb Q_p(K∪K')$ mean? What restriction does the appending of the set impose on the element $v_h$? Or is $v_h$ just any polynomial and you want to know how its value may differ over two sets that are a distance $\sim h$ apart?

Comment: Hello @LutzL. $v_h\in\mathbb{Q}_p(K\cup K')$ means that $v_h$ is a polynomial of degree $\le p$ in each variable restricted to $K\cup K'$.

Comment: What makes it different from a polynomial of the same degree structure defined on the whole plane $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: I think there is no difference

Comment: And would it be a sensible "training" problem to ask what maximum value a polynomial can take on $B(0,2h)$ if its values are bounded by $1$ on $B(0,h)$? ($B(x,r)$ being the ball around $x$ of radius $r$.)

Comment: $C$ doesn't really depends on $h$, one can get rid of its dependence by scaling. The relative location of the square does seem to matter. if $K$ and $K'$ are sharing an edge, one can use Chebyshev polynomial to get an lower bound $C \ge T_p(3)$. If $K$ and $K'$ are related by a translation along the diagonal for a distance $h$ (i.e. sharing a vertex), the lower bound becomes $C \ge T_p(3)^2$. 
This kind of lower bounds increases very quickly when one  move $K$ and $K'$ away or increases $p$.

Comment: Dear @achillehui, could you explain to me how I can employ Chebyshev polynomials to get such a lower bound? And what about the general case where $dist(K,K')\sim Ch$?

Comment: @Lutzl In 1D it is $2^p$

Comment: For simplicity, consider the 1-d counterpart and assume $h = 2$. Translate everything so that $K = [1,3]$ and $K' = [-1,1]$, Over $K'$, $|x| \le 1 \implies |T_p(x)| = |\cos(p\cos^{-1}(x))| \le 1$. On $K$, $|T_p(x)|$ reaches maximum at $x = 3$ with value $T_p(3)$.
This establish $C \ge T_p(3)$ in the 1-d case. This example can be lifted to 2-d to give a lower bound of $C \ge T_p(3)$ when $K$ and $K'$ share an edge. For the other case where $K$ and $K'$ only share a vertex, $T_p(x)T_p(y)$ will give you a lower bound $C \ge T_p(3)^2$

Comment: @achillehui hence if I suppose that $K,K'$ are not neighbours any more, but still their distance is proportional to $h$, then the constant $C$ will depend on $h$ as well. Am I right?

Comment: @avati91 Nope. $C$ depends on $C_1$ but not on $h$ (assume you scale $K$ and $K'$ by same amount when you change $h$).

Comment: @avati91 Assume I didn't make any mistake, I have found the optimal bound for the general case. Let $\Delta(x) = \max(1,|T_p(x)|)$. If you apply an affine transform to turn $K'$ into $[-1,1]^2$, the optimal $C$ will be $\max\limits_{(x,y)\in K}(\Delta(x)\Delta(y))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I start, I'll like to point out:

The coefficient $C$ is invariant under global affine transformations of the plane. In particular, $C$ doesn't depend on $h$ explicitly. If you place $K$ and $K'$ at a distance $C_1 h$ apart
and scale $K$, $K'$ and their separation by same amount, same $C$ follows.

With this in mind, we can transform the question as follows:

- Pick a fixed integer $p > 0$.
- Let $Y \subset \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ be the set of polynomials in $x,y$ whose degree in both $x, y$ are at most $p$.
- Let $K'$ be the square $[-1,1]^2$ and $K$ be another square of side $2$.
- For any $f \in Y$, let $\|f\|_K$ and  $\|f\|_{K'}$ be the sup-norm of $f$ over $K$ and $K'$.

  - $\|f\|_K = \sup\limits_{(x,y) \in K} |f(x,y)|$
  - $\|f\|_{K'} = \sup\limits_{(x,y) \in K'} |f(x,y)|$
- Let $Y_1 = \{ f \in Y \;|\; \|f\|_{K'} \le 1 \}$

The questions become what are the coefficient $C$ to make following works:

$$\|f\|_K \le C \|f\|_{K'}, \;\forall f \in Y
\quad\iff\quad \|f\|_K \le C,\;\forall f \in Y_1$$
This is equivalent to $\sup\limits_{f\in Y_1} \|f\|_K\;\le\; C$. Independent of
where $K$ is located, what we need is compute/estimate $\sup\limits_{f\in Y_1} \|f\|_K$.

To my surprise, it is possible to compute this value.

To do this, we need to look at a related 1-dim problem.

- Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}[x]$ be the set of polynomials in $x$ with degree at most $p$.
- For $f \in X$, let $\|f\|_I$ be the sup-norm of $f$ over $I = [-1,1]$.

  - $\|f\|_I = \sup\limits_{x\in I}|f(x)|$.
- Let $X_1 = \big\{ f \in X : \|f\|_I \le 1 \big\}$

The new problem is given $t \in \mathbb{R}$, what is $\Delta(t) \stackrel{def}{=} \sup\limits_{f \in X_1}|f(t)|$?

Let's consider what happens when $t > 1$.

For any $f \in X_1$ and $\epsilon > 0$, consider the function:
$$g(x) = (1+\epsilon)T_p(x) - f(x)$$

Let $x_k = \cos\frac{k\pi}{p}$ for $k = 0,1,\ldots,p$. Since $T_p(x)$ reaches $+1$ and $-1$ alternatively at these $p+1$ points, we find
$$g(x_0) > 0, g(x_1) < 0, g(x_2) > 0,\ldots$$

This forces $g(x)$ to have at least $p$ roots $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_p$ with $\lambda_i \in (x_{i},x_{i-1})$. Since $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $p$, these are all the roots of $g(x)$. 
$g(x)$ can be factorized as $A\prod_{i=1}^p(x - \lambda_i)$ for some constant $A$. Since  $g(x_0) > 0$ and $x_0 > \lambda_i$ for all $i$, we find $A > 0$.

Since $t > 1 = x_0$, this leads to

$$(1+\epsilon)T_p(t) - f(t) = A\prod_{i=1}^p(t - x_i) > 0
\implies (1+\epsilon)T_p(t) > f(t)
$$
Apply a similar argument to $-f(x)$, we can deduce $(1+\epsilon)T_p(t) > |f(t)|$.

Since this is true for all $f \in X_1$, we get $(1+\epsilon)T_p(t) \ge \sup_{f\in X_1}|f(t)|$

Since this is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, we obtain $T_p(t) \ge \sup_{f\in X_1}|f(t)|$

Since the bound $T_p(t)$ can be reached by taking $f(x)$ to $T_p(x)$, we have

$$\Delta(t) = \sup_{f\in X_1}|f(t)| = T_p(t)\quad\text{ for } t > 1$$

It is clear $\Delta(t) = 1$ for $|t| \le 1$ and $\Delta(t)$ is an even function in $t$. This implies

$$\Delta(t) = \max(1,|T_p(t)|)$$

With this 1-dim result at hand, we can ask a similar 2-dim question:

What is 
$\Delta(x,y) \stackrel{def}{=} \sup\limits_{f\in Y_1}|f(x,y)|$?

1. If $(x,y) \in K' = I^2$, $\Delta(x,y)$ is trivially $1$.
2. If one of $x,y \in I$, say $y \in I$, then for any $f\in Y_1$, $f(\cdot,y) \in X_1$. By above 1-dim result, it is easy to deduce $\Delta(x,y) = \Delta(x)$.  Similarly, $\Delta(x,y) = \Delta(y)$ when $x \in I$.
3. When both $x, y \not\in I$, we can apply result in step 2. to deduce
   $|f(x,s)| \le \Delta(x)$ for all $f \in Y_1, s \in I$. Apply the 1-dim result
   to $h \in X_1$ where $h(s) = \frac{f(x,s)}{\Delta(x)}$, we can deduce
   $$\sup_{f\in Y_1}\left(\frac{f(x,y)}{\Delta(x')}\right) = 
   \sup_{f\in Y_1} h(y) \le \sup_{h\in X_1} h(y) = \Delta(y)$$
   This leads to $\Delta(x,y) = \sup\limits_{f\in Y_1}f(x,y) \le \Delta(x)\Delta(y)$. Since the bound on RHS is achieved by $f(s,t) = T_p(s)T_p(t)$, we can conclude $\Delta(x,y) = \Delta(x)\Delta(y)$ in this case.

Combine all these, we have

$$\Delta(x,y) = \Delta(x)\Delta(y) = \max(1,|T_p(x)|)\max(1,|T_p(y)|)$$
Armed with this function, it is easy to see the target "sup" can be computed by following formula.

$$\bbox[border:1px solid blue;padding: 1em]{C_{optimal} = \sup_{f\in Y_1} \|f\|_K =  \max_{(x,y)\in K}\Delta(x)\Delta(y)}$$

For example,

1. When $K$ is sharing an edge with $K'$, say $K = [1,3]\times[-1,1]$, the largest $\Delta(x,y)$ in $K$ is achieved at $(3,\cdot)$.
   In this case, $C_{optimal} = \Delta(3) = T_p(3)$.
2. When $K$ is axis aligned and sharing an vertex with $K'$, say $K = [1,3]^2$,
   the largest $\Delta(x,y)$ in $K$ is achieved at $(3,3)$. In this case, $C_{optimal} = \Delta(3,3) = \Delta(3)^2 = T_p(3)^2$.

For other configuration where $K$ is separated by a distance $C_1h$ from $K'$, one can compute the optimal $C$ in a similar manner.

Let's say $K$ and $K'$ are related by a translation of distance $C_1h$. Under the affine transformation which 
maps $K'$ to $I^2$, the center of $K$ will be located at a distance $c = \sqrt{8}C_1$ from the origin. 
Let's say the center is  $(c\cos\theta,c\sin\theta)$ for some $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Over $K$,
$\Delta(x,y)$ will be maximized at the vertex $( 1 + c\cos\theta, 1 + c\sin\theta )$. In this case
$C_{optimal} = T_p(1+c\cos\theta)T_p(1+c\sin\theta)$.

When $K$ is not axis aligned with $K'$, it is not immediately obvious which point in $K$ will maximize $\Delta(x,y)$. I'll leave the fun (or mess?) to you.