# Find a polynomial of degree $\leq n$ such that $p(0)=1$ and $p$ has smallest supremum norm on $[1,2]$

Tags: polynomials, computational-mathematics

Of course, if $n=0$ then $p=1$.

I found myself that if $n=1$ then $p=1-x\frac23$, just by seeing that $p(1)$ must be 
$-p(2)$ cause $p$ is monotone.

What about $n>1$?
I thought about sth related to Tschebyschev polynomials (scaled and translated) but it does not make sense after longer thinking.

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that what you want to do is to make a polynomial that has all its roots spread out in some strategic way on $[1,2]$ (consider that your $n=1$ solution has a root at $1.5$). I would play around with that for $n=2$ and $n=3$ and see if I found a pattern.

Comment: My thinking is similar to Arthur's. My first guess would be that the quadratic solution is a linear combination of $1$ and $(2x-3)^2$. That would yield
$$p_2(x)=1-\frac{24}{17}x+\frac{8}{17}x^2$$ as a candidate. The minimum at $x=3/2$ is then $-1/17$ whereas $p_2(1)=p_2(2)=1/17$. No idea for a proof or a generalization though. +1 for suggesting Tschebyshev here (they form a solution to a related problem, but the details of that one have been erased from my brain by the teeth of time).

Comment: Actually that suggestion would match nicely with Chebyshev/Tschebyshev/whatever translitteration you use. $T_2(3)=17$ explaining the scaling factor I got. When the center is moved to $x=3/2$, and the interval $[-1,1]$ moved to $[1,2]$, the constraint at $x=0$ is three units off the center. Given all this I would begin by trying to check whether
$$p_n(x)=\frac{T_n(3-2x)}{T_n(3)}$$ gives the best possible results. But,  I'm not gonna bet any serious money on this.  A beer, may be?

Comment: $$p_3(x) = 1-\frac{70}{33}x+\frac{16}{11}x^2-\frac{32}{99}x^3$$ yields $1/99$.

Comment: I was just about to suggest the exact same cubic @RobPratt gave. His $p_3(x)$ matches with my suggestion. As the next step $$p_4(x)=\frac{128 x^4}{577}-\frac{768 x^3}{577}+\frac{1696 x^2}{577}-\frac{1632 x}{577}+1$$ would give $1/577$.

Comment: $$p_5(x)=1-3.53556x +4.92425 
3x^2 -3.37802x^3 
+1.14187 x^4
-0.15225 x^5$$
yields $0.0002973068$, which is slightly better than the proposed formula.

Comment: Maciej, can you elaborate on why you think Chebyshev might not be best here?

Comment: @RobPratt I got $p_5(2)=-0.000348$ with your suggestion? Is there a rounding error? Anyway, that would be worse than $T_5(3-2x)/T_5(3)$ giving a sup norm of $1/3363\approx0.000297354$.

Comment: Yes, it was a combination of rounding and typo.  The last digit of the $x^2$ coefficient was wrong.  With more digits: $$1−3.53556032127487 x+4.92425067879084 x^2−3.37801594533084 x^3+1.14187402779274x^4−0.15225113317056x^5$$ I discretized by looking at values from 1 to 2 by 0.0001, so this is still only an approximation.

Comment: @RobPratt I don't know if my Mathematica rounded something when I copy/pasted your polynomial. At low resolution the plots of the two polynomials are identical. But according to its calculations your polynomial has a "higher" value around the largest maximum. With your $p_5$, Mathematica thinks $p_5(1.904)\approx 0.000297546>1/3363$.

Comment: Yes, this is just numerical noise.  The coefficients I supplied are still rounded.

Comment: Hmm. I take that back. Mathematica apparently rounded the copy/paste numbers to six digits or something. Too late now. May be tomorrow.

Comment: Just a thought - it might be instructive to solve the similar problem where $p$ is a continuous piece-wise linear curve of $n$ pieces. I suspect the polynomial solution will have similar behavior.

Comment: Yes You all are probably right about this. But how to justify that these scaled and translated Tschebyschew works? I notified by alternation theorem that p is even/odd with respect to 3/2 depending on even/odd n. And it has to be analogically +-1 in point 3 because if we were to require p(3)=+-1 then exercise has the same solution up to sign as with p(0)=1. But Tn(1)=1 but Tn does not minimize norm on [-1;0] among polynomials Such that p(1)=1. So it is very sensitive problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loosely speaking, among all polynomials whose magnitude over $[-1,1]$ is restricted, the [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) $T_n(x)$ grows fastest outside $[-1,1]$. More precisely,

> Let $f(x)$ be any polynomial with degree at most $n$ and $|f(x)| \le 1$ over $[-1,1]$. For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
>   $$|f(x)| \le \max(1,|T_n(x)|)$$

For a proof, see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3370465/59379) to an unrelated question about Chebyshev polynomials.

Back to the question at hand.

Let $p(x)$ be any polynomial with degree $n$ with $p(0) = 1$ and sup-norm $M= \sup\limits_{x \in [1,2]}|p(x)|$ over $[1,2]$. It is easy to see $f(x) = \frac1M p\left(\frac{3-x}{2}\right)$ is a polynomial with degree $n$ and $|f(x)| \le 1 $ over $[-1,1]$. Apply above result, we find

$$1 = p(0) = M |f(3)| \le M \max(1,|T_n(3)|) = M T_n(3)\quad\implies\quad
M \ge \frac{1}{T_n(3)}$$

The lower bound $\frac{1}{T_n(3)}$ is achievable with

$$f(x) = T_n(x)\quad\iff\quad p(x) = \frac{T_n(3-2x)}{T_n(3)}$$

This means $\frac{T_n(3-2x)}{T_n(3)}$ is a polynomial with degree $n$ with smallest sup-norm over $[1,2]$.

Comment: Nice. I gave this bounty to user125932 for A) he got one more vote, B) needs the points more :-) I mayy return to that other question later.

Answer (score 6):

Using Jyrki's conjectured form and slightly adjusting the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Minimal_%E2%88%9E-norm) of minimality from the Wikipedia page on Chebyshev polynomials:

Define $\| p \| = \sup_{x \in [1, 2]} |p(x)|$, and let $p_n = \frac{T_n(3 - 2x)}{T_n(3)}$, so $p_n$ has degree $\leq n$ and $p_n(0) = 1$. Note that we have $|p_n(x)| = \|p_n\|$ at the $n+1$ points $x_k = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\cos \frac{k\pi}{n}$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$ (where each $x_k \in [1, 2]$), and $p_n$ alternates in sign on $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n$. Suppose there were some polynomial $q$ of degree $\leq n$ with $q(0) = 1$ and $\|q\| < \|p_n\|$. Then defining $f = p_n - q$, since $\|q\| < \|p_n\|$, subtracting $q$ does not change the sign of $p_n$ at the points with $|p_n(x)| = \|p_n\|$, meaning $f$ also alternates in sign on $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n$. But by the IVT, $f$ then has at least $n$ roots on the interval $[1, 2]$ (one between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ for each $0 \leq i < n$), and $f$ has another root at $x = 0$, for a total of $n+1$ roots, which is impossible as $f$ has degree $\leq n$. This means there is no such $q$, so $p_n$ minimizes $\|\cdot \|$ among all polynomials with degree $\leq n$.

Comment: It's worth noting that the same proof shows that $T_n(x)/T_n(a)$ minimizes the norm $\sup_{x \in [-1, 1]} |p(x)|$ among all polynomials of degree $\leq n$ with $p(a) = 1$ for any fixed $a \not \in [-1, 1]$. Equivalently for any $a \not \in [-1, 1]$, $T_n(x)$ maximizes $|p(a)|$ over all polynomials of degree $\leq n$ with $\sup_{x \in [-1, 1]} |p(x)| \leq 1$.

Comment: thanks for the bounty!

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the nice self-contained answer. Do check out achille hui's answer to the linked question as well :-)