# Polynomial that grows faster than any other polynomial outside $[−1,1]^n$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation-theory, chebyshev-polynomials

Consider this statement: "Chebyshev polynomials increase in magnitude more quickly outside the range $[−1,1]$ than any other polynomial that is restricted to have magnitude no greater than one inside the range $[−1,1]$."

In the multivariate case, is there a degree $d$ polynomial that lies in $[-1,1]$ in the interval $[-1,1]^n$ and grows faster than any other polynomial of degree $d$ outside the $[-1,1]^n$? If so, what is this polynomial? It is natural to conjecture that $q(x_1,..,,x_n) = T_{d/n}(x_1)T_{d/n}(x_2)..T_{d/n}(x_n)$ (assuming $n|d$) is this polynomial ($T_i(x)$ is the degree $i$ Chebyshev polynomial).

For the univariate case, a proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2047666/chebyshev-polynomials-increase-more-quickly-than-any-other-polynomial-outside).

I have tried to generalize this proof to the bivariate case, but the fact that bivariate polynomials can have infinitely many roots (while univariate polynomials can have only at most degree-many roots) seems to be a barrier in adapting the proof.

Comment: How do you compare growth rates in multiple dimensions? In the direction away from the origin? Along all axes, away from the origin?

Comment: I define $p$ grows faster than $q$ outside a bounded set $\mathcal{D}$ as: for all $x \not\in \mathcal{D}$, $|p(x)| \geq |q(x)|$.

Comment: Hi! Take a look at this I think it answers your question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281115/a-bounded-polynomial-having-bounded-coefficients-several-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the 2D case, and the line $x=x_0$, for $x_0 \in (-1,1)$. Along that line, the fastest growing polynomial is a Chebyshev polynomial.

A Chebyshev polynomial in $y$ multiplied by $f(x)=1$ will make a "multivariate" polynomial that is in $[-1,1]$ in the unit box, and grows faster than any polynomial on $[-1,1] \times ((-\infty,-1) \cup(1,\infty))$.

However, this polynomial grows much more poorly outside of that region.

I think you need to relax your definition of growth. No single multivariate polynomial will grow most quickly everywhere.

Comment: "No single multivariate polynomial will grow most quickly everywhere." Did you prove that?

Comment: The example I provided was not sufficient? It grows faster than any other on the stated region, and slower than many others elsewhere.

Comment: You are right. It is sufficient. Nice argument!

Comment: Im sorry, I don’t think you’re proving that. At the most you’re showing that, if such a growing polynomial exists, then it can’t be a product of polynomials in each of the variables separately.

Comment: @FedePoncio the polynomial described in the second paragraph is uniquely maximal over that domain (given degree $d$). Because we're dealing with polynomials, its on that domain fully determine its values everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The product of Chebyshev polynomials does not seem to be the fastest growing polynomials outside the $L_{\infty}$ unit ball, at least for $n=2$. It looks like that for all even $d$, $x^d/3+y^d/3$ is greater in absolute value than $T_{d/2}(x)T_{d/2}(y)$ in some region outside the $L_{\infty}$ unit ball.

See the Desmos plots for $d=$ [$2$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/44dirza38i), [$4$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/14txyaj1kq) and [$6$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wnk8m6zmbb).

These examples in fact shows that, for a fixed $p \geq 1$, $n$, and $d$, the product of Chebyshev polynomials (with individual degrees $d/n$) need not grow faster all other degree $d$ polynomials outside the unit ball in $L_p$ norm. Hence, some of the other natural ways to generalize the one-dimensional case to higher dimensions is ruled out.

Whether there *exist* degree $d$ polynomials (bounded in the $L_{\infty}$ unit ball) that grows faster than all other degree $d$ polynomials (that are bounded in the unit ball) outside the unit ball is still not clear.